# python reduce sqlite3 db lookups

Tags: python, database, sqlite, singleton, shared-memory

I am trying to reduce sqlite3 db look ups in python. I have system with limited RAM of 1 GB only where i am implementing it. I want to store current DB values somewhere from where i can retrieve them without consulting DB again and again. One thing to keep in mind is that trigger point of all of my python scripts (processes) is different and there is no master script or you can say i am not controlling all of my scripts from one point.

**What's in my knowledge:**

1. I don't want to save/retrieve data from file as i don't want to make read/write operations. In a nutshell i don't want to manipulate it via file (Simply saying no to pickel and [shelve](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html) python modules)
2. I also cannot use in memory cache modules like [memcahced](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-memcached) and beaker because of limitation of memory size and also these modules are intended for server side development and i am working on stand alone scripts (iot device)
3. I cannot use singleton classes because of limitation of namespaces and scope. As soon as scope of one script ends, instance of singleton also vanishes and i am not able to persist instance of singleton class in all of my python scripts. I am not able to use static variables and static methods too because instance does not stick in scope and everything becomes volatile and goes back to initialized value instead of current DB values every next time i import singleton class script in any of my other scripts.
4. As trigger point of all of my python scripts is different which also makes it impossible to use global variables too. Global variables are required to be initialized with some value whereas i want current DB values in global variables.
5. I also cannot do memory segmentation as python does not allow me to do so.

> *What else can i do more?*

Is there any python library or any other language's library which allows me to insert current DB values so that i instead of looking up from Sqlite3 DB i get values from there without doing any read/write operation?? *(By read/write operation i mean not to load from hard drive or sd card)*

Thanks in advance, any help from you is highly appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like the best thing to do is to *store the data in the db and read it when you need it*. What makes to think this needs optimising?

Comment: I don't want to waste read/write operations as i have very limited read/write operations available. It's iot device related which needs to be remain in user's hands for years, really don't want to consume read/write operations, already doing hell lot of DB operations.